# Code keeps displaying variable even after it is deleted

Tags: c++, oop

I am still new to c++ and just started to learn about classes and OOP. I have been practicing trying to make classes out of any item I can think of, so I made a phone class. Code is below. The problem is no matter what number I give it, it displays the same WRONG number everytime. The crazy thing is in the beginning I had given the phone class a variable to store its own number and gave the class instance its own number. That number is the number it keeps wanting to "call". Even after going back several times and making sure I wasn't calling the wring variable I completely deleted the variable and the code still displays the same number. The number is 214-748-3647. Makes me feel like my computer is haunted. Could anyone help?

*CODE DOESN'T ACTUALLY MAKE ANY SORT OF PHONE CALL OR ANY CONNECTION WHAT SO EVER*

*PHONE CLASS HEADER*

```
#ifndef PHONE_H_INCLUDED
#define PHONE_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Phone{
public:

    string Brand;
    int Serial;
    string CellId;

    void Call();

private:

    void Dial(int NumberToDial);

    void EndCall();

};


#endif // PHONE_H_INCLUDED
```

*PHONE SOURCE CODE*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "phone.h"

using namespace std;

void Phone::Call(){

    string UserInput = "0";
    int NumberToCall = 0;

    cout << "What number would you like to call?" << endl << endl;

    getline(cin, UserInput);

    if(UserInput.length() != 10){

        cout << endl << "invalid digits" << endl;
        Call();

    }
    else{

        stringstream(UserInput) >> NumberToCall;
        Dial(NumberToCall);

    }
}

void Phone::Dial(int NumberToDial = 0){

    ostringstream converter;
    string Number;

    converter << NumberToDial;
    Number = converter.str();

    cout << "Dialing ";

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        cout << Number[i];

        if(i==2){

            cout << "-";
        }

        if(i==5){

            cout << "-";

        }

    }

    cout << endl << endl << "Press any key to end the call..." << endl << endl;


    cin.get();

    EndCall();


}

void Phone::EndCall(){

    cout << "Call ended." << endl << endl;

}
```

*Aaaaannnnd my MAIN*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "phone.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    Phone MyPhone;

    MyPhone.Brand = "iPhone 5";
    MyPhone.CellId = "F2D9G3A2";
    MyPhone.Serial = 1411512;

    MyPhone.Call();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you still have an old build of the previous version. Make sure when you change your source code that it's actually rebuilt before running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple answer. You're code and logic is fine. The error occurs because you convert the `std::string` which holds the phone number to an integer. This is a problem because a typical 10 digit phone number is too big to fit inside the `int` type. Have a look here to see the min and max numbers you can fit in different types: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

Look at this line here actually.

> Maximum value for an object of type long int: 2147483647 (231-1) or greater

Funny how the max value is that mysterious phone number.

Comment: WOW! What a coincidence! His previous phone number that he probably made up exactly matched the maximum value of long int.....

Comment: Actually, if he's using VS then the value of an int is automatically assigned to 2147483647 if it is not assigned on initialization.  My guess is the stringstream is failing because of overflow and not changing the int's value at all.